can I use riverpod and a database like sqflite or firebase at the same time?
I have a riverpod model in my app which contains a list of items and I'm calling this riverpod model in different screens to use the list of items and show them on the screen with help of ListView. in one of the screens that I am using this list of items, at the same time I'm fetching the data from my database and assign it to the riverpod model. the problem is that when I come back from that screen, my riverpod model is empty.
here is my riverpod model:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

import 'package:coffee_shop_app/models/coffee.dart';

Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
  final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  final db = await sql.openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'coffee.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE cart_provider(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, coffeeImage TEXT, CoffeeName TEXT, CoffeePrice REAL)');
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  return db;
}

class CartNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  CartNotifier({required this.coffees});
  
  List<Coffee> coffees;

  Future<void> loadCoffee() async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    final data = await db.query('cart_provider');
    final registeredCoffees = data
        .map(
          (row) => Coffee(
            id: row['id'] as String,
            coffeeImage: row['coffeeImage'] as String,
            coffeeName: row['CoffeeName'] as String,
            coffeePrice: row['CoffeePrice'] as double,
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    coffees = registeredCoffees;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> addCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    if (coffees.contains(coffee)) {
      return;
    } else {
      final db = await _getDatabase();
      await db.insert(
        'cart_provider',
        {
          'id': coffee.id,
          'coffeeImage': coffee.coffeeImage,
          'CoffeeName': coffee.coffeeName,
          'CoffeePrice': coffee.coffeePrice,
        },
      );

      coffees = [...coffees, coffee];
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void removeCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    await db.delete(
      'cart_provider',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [coffee.id],
    );

    coffees = coffees.where((c) => c != coffee).toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final cartProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<CartNotifier>((ref) {
  return CartNotifier(coffees: []);
});

and here is the screen that I am calling initState to fetch data and assign it to my riverpod:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'package:coffee_shop_app/provider/cart_provider.dart';
import 'package:coffee_shop_app/components/registered_coffee_item.dart';

class CartScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const CartScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CartScreen> createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends ConsumerState<CartScreen> {
  late Future<void> _coffeesFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _coffeesFuture = ref.read(cartProvider.notifier).loadCoffee();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final registeredCoffees = ref.watch(cartProvider).coffees;

    if (registeredCoffees.isEmpty) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text(
          'There is no coffee here, add some!',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return             FutureBuilder(
      future: _coffeesFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) =>
          snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
              ? const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20,
                          vertical: 20,
                        ),
                        child: ListView(
                          children: [
                            ...registeredCoffees.map((coffee) {
                              return RegisteredCoffeeItem(
                                coffee: coffee,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                              );
                            }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
    );
  }
}

I ran the app without calling database and everything was okay. I really don't understand why I can't use riverpod and sqflite at the same time and it is causing me problems in other screens that I'm using riverpod
if you need more information please tell me

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

I'm not familiar with futureProvider, streamProvider and .... would you suggest bloc state management in this situation ? can I fix this problem with bloc ? what is the problem of riverpod tools ?!

Flutter has many state managers, the best are bloc and riverpod/hook . You can use what you want. I suggest you riverpod/flutterHooks (to use together). read the documentation, it is easy. suggestions: the loadCoffee() why in the init ? you can use Async Providers , it easy and better.
